# Update github markdown Tasklists ( GFM ) via commit

Tags: github, task, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

As you know you can create a tasklist in **GFM** *(github flavoured markdown)* by using the tags

```
- [ ] for unchecked task
- [x] for a checked task
```

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to check a task in a given issue's tasklist by commeinting it in a commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the simple answer is NO, you cannot tick task list by adding comments to a commit message.

But what you can actually do, along with a commit you can update the `.markdown` that contains this list.

Comment: Given that issues reside on Github and not in the code, how can you update the markdown along with a commit? Could you provide an example?

Comment: well ... How? I guess we will never know