# Checking issue task on GitHub using commit messages

Tags: github, git-commit

It's rather easy to refer and close a GitHub issue by referring to it in a commit message and using specific words (i.e. *closes*):

```
This code change closes #123
```

As "*closes #123*" is being used in commit message it will automatically close issue #123 on GitHub.

But what if we had an issue with a task list? How can we manipulate these checkboxes using commit messages to avoid overhead work with GitHub? **Is it possible?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update github markdown Tasklists ( GFM ) via commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419149/update-github-markdown-tasklists-gfm-via-commit)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible currently

Comment: Each box needs to be numbered with an integer., so in an issue with three checkboxes, you could allow a reference such as #123.1 #123.2 #123.3

Comment: Hey @tropicalrambler, how to number the checkboxes?
If we do something like: `- 1[  ]` this doesn't become a checkbox

Comment: For now it does not, but the code for github (and others) could be changed, so that a commit message that includes "#123.1"  would mark the box proposal you put forth" - 1[  ]"  as " - 1[X]"  The trick would be to propose an assembled structure and protocol to GitHub, Gitlab, etc. A roadshow needs to be assembled.